# C++: Can I instantiate an object inside a void function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

For the purposes of the program I'm making, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
void instantiate(myType t){

   t = new myType();

}

int main(){

   myType* t = NULL;

   .
   .
   .

   instantiate(t);

   .
   .
   .

   if (t != NULL){
      do something;
   }
}
```

However, any person that knows C++ knows that, after getting out of the function's scope, t will continue to be NULL. But is there any way of making this work as I want? To make it clear, it HAS to be a void function (cannot be something like "t = instantiate()"), because it will be used to instantiate more than just one type of class at the same function.

EDIT: songyuanyao's comment solved my problem, but since people in the comments suggested that there could be a better solution if I gave more details about my scenario, here it is:

```
void instantiateHash(Ohash*& OH, Chash*& CH, HOhash*& HOH, int type, int size, int limit){

    if (type == 1){
        OH = new Ohash(size, type);
    }else if (type == 2){
        CH = new Chash(size, type);
    }else{
        HOH = new HOhash(size, limit);
    }
}

void insertIntoHash(Ohash*& OH, Chash*& CH, HOhash*& HOH, string s){

    //The functions for operations in the hashtables are different for each type
    if (OH != NULL){
        OH->insert(s);
    }else if (CH != NULL){
        CH->insert(s, CH->table, CH->size);
    }else{
        HOH->insert(s, CH->table, CH->limit);
    }

}

void mainMenu(int t, int s, int l){

    Ohash* OH   = NULL;
    Chash* CH   = NULL;
    HOhash* HOH = NULL;
    string str;    

    //Instantiates a particular type of hashtable according to the type variable
    instanciateHash(OH, CH, HOH, t, s, l);

    cout<<"Enter the word you want to insert into your new hashtable:"<<endl;
    cin<<str;

    //then inserts something into it
    insertIntoHash(OH, CH, HOH, str);
}

int main(){

    int type, size, limit;

    .
    //intructions that ask the user to enter the 3 values for type, size and limit
    .

    mainMenu(type, size, limit);

}
```

Above is a simplified representation of my program's structure. I want to have generic functions that can operate on three types of hashtables. I believe the way I handled it looks pretty amateurish, but it's because it's a very old code that i'm now adding new stuff, for a College project. I tried to learn to use templates, virtual functions, but it was getting harder than I expected (because, although each class has functions for the same operations (like inserting, removing, etc), they have different constructors and some functions receive different parameters, and I don't have time right now to rewrite everything from scratch.

Comment: Pass-by-reference, i.e. `void instantiate(myType*& t)`.

Comment: The toolbox that we call C++ has a large number of tools. I am sure one of them will work for you. However, you have to be less wishy-washy about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, songyuanyao, that was it. I tried it in a vareity of ways, but wasn't getting the *s and &s right.

Comment: I think this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). It would be nice if you can tell us the bigger picture of what you're trying to do here since there might be a better way than what you're currently doing.

Comment: You say, "t will be used to instantiate more than just one type of class at the same function." In that case, you'll need a template. What are you really trying to do? Perhaps you need a template. Perhaps you want a virtual base class. Probably you do not need `new` and pointers. What are you up to REALLY?

Comment: Editted with more info.

Comment: Looks like you want polymorphism.  Use inheritance and virtual member functions.

Comment: Well that changes everything. The original signature only had one parameter, so we didn't know what  you meant by, "it will be used to instantiate more than just one type of class at the same function." We assumed you wanted some kind of polymorphism. "The same function", as it turns out, has three parameters, not one. Next time, pleeeease include a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ 17, you can just use an `std::variant` to hold exactly one of the 3 different implementations, even if they don't share a common interface.

Of course if they do, just use polymorphism and just declare the pointer as the base type.

The partial solution you found still has a problem though, it leaks. You will either need to write a matching destructor which deletes the instantiated objects again, or easier: Just use smart instead of raw pointers, you have them available since C++ 11.

Specifically a `std::unique_pointer` would be appropriate for this use case. The pattern of passing the pointer by reference on order to assign it still works with smart pointers, except that you don't have to worry about the pointer already owning am object.